# Sharepoint List Error: There has been an error while loading the form

Tags: forms, sharepoint, powerapps, sharepoint-list

I have a Sharepoint List connected to a Form created in PowerApps. The info is saving correctly, but when trying to open a item of the list in order to view the attachments, it shows the following error:

[image]

Do you know how to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Whether this issue occurs on all items?